# How to write bash script that continuosly watch terminal commands?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I want to write a bash script that keep watching entered commands on terminal. Like if user entered `rm` command on terminal, the bash program will ask if he really want to delete the file, if `Y` entered, deleting operation will be performed.

Comment: U could add `alias rm="rm -i"` in your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: Take a look at this : https://github.com/rcaloras/bash-preexec

Answer (score 4):

First, with `rm` you don't really need to do this.  If you want `rm` to always prompt you, you should do something like:

```
rm() { command rm -i "$@"; }
```

which defines a function that injects `-i` every time you invoke `rm`.  (Put the above line in your startup files so it gets defined in every interactive shell.)

But, `bash` does give you the ability to do what you (seem to) want with the DEBUG trap.  It is a function that executes before every command that you enter interactively.  For example, to use your example and prompt for removal with `rm`, you could do something like:

```
$ debug_trap() { case $BASH_COMMAND in rm*) read -p "Do you really want to rm $@? ";
    if test "$REPLY" != Y; then echo aborting; return 1; fi;; esac; } >&2
$ trap debug_trap DEBUG
$ shopt -s extdebug
```

(The extdebug is necessary so that returning non-zero from the trap function prevents the command from being executed) But this is absurdly fragile.  This will *not* reliably capture all invocations of `rm` and attempting to make it robust is almost certainly destined to fail.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Do you know what should i do to make it run in background?Deamon, service,process or something different? So if i open a terminal and use rm command, the bash script will catch it and prompt me "Do you really want to rm".

Comment: It doesn't make sense to run it as a daemon.  The debug trap is executed by the shell before it executes every command.

Comment: @zzzr store the first shown `rm()` function in your `.bashrc`, log out and log back in, and then `rm` will do what you want without a daemon.